# Export SQL Binary/BLOB Data?

Tags: sql-server, export, blob

Recently a software application we utilize upgraded from ASP to ASP.NET. In the process they abandoned the old web-based product and rewrote the entire UI, using new DB tables. The old DB tables still exist in the database and contain legacy files in binary or blob formats. I'm wondering if there is an easy way to export all these legacy files from the database to the filesystem (NTFS)? Then we could delete these old unused tables and save a few GB of space in the DB backups, etc.

Comment: I don't think this is a ServerFault question, every DB programmer will find this of interest (me, for example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the 2008 Books Online (search - OpenSqlFilestream) That API has great examples and may help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try [SqlLobEditor](http://www.handyarchive.com/Business/Database-Management/61973-SqlLobEditor.html). It has a 30-day trial.